# cannot find symbol import android.app.Person

Tags: codenameone

I am building my own notification tray natively in Android. I am trying to use the less-obsolete `android.app.Notification` resources (instead of the now-deprecated `NotificationCompat` ones)

In one case I want to build a `MessagingStyle` with a bitmap icon. To do this, the class `android.app.Person` is required. (`MessagingStyle` doesn't support bitmat icons in `NotificationCompat`)

Looking at the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Person) I can see that `android.app.Person` was added in API level 28. CN1's build server throws the error `cannot find symbol import android.app.Person`. Is this because CN1 targets SDK 27, am I correct? Can I use some build hint to include a higher one that allows me to use `android.app.Person`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it works when adding build hint `android.buildToolsVersion=28`